# How to view socket info when SO_DEBUG is enabled on socket (windows)?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, networking

```
int setsockopt(
  SOCKET s,
  int level,
  int optname,
  const char* optval,
  int optlen
);
```

**SO_DEBUG**

Windows Sockets service providers are encouraged (but not required) to supply 
    output debug   information if the SO_DEBUG option is set by an application. 
    The mechanism for generating the    debug information and the form it takes
    are beyond the scope of this document.

I did not find any scope.

Comment: This so-called provider-dependent debug information seems very esoteric anyway. Why not use sniffers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work on win32.

> Enables debug output. Microsoft
>   providers currently do not output any
>   debug information.

I believe it was pulled with a lot of other stuff to maintain some compatibility with the BSD socket APIs.